# Importing Plotly for R into Flask

Tags: python, flask, bioinformatics

Currently I understand how to import a python module into Flask, for example below the module 'myfunctions' is being imported and a function from it is being called.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from myfunctions import printtext
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template('echo.html')
```

But how would one approach importing an R script- written with Plotly for R commands? Would it be done with the same principle or can you not import something which isn't 'Pythonic'? Will we instead have to somehow export data to it from our web-app?

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer is no, you cannot import R code as a Python module. But, there are ways to weave R scripts into Python. I'll quickly address a few here:

**1) Use bash to run two different scripts.**

This is a very common way to integrate scripts written in different languages:

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
python mypythonscript.py > data.txt
Rscript myrscript.r -i data.txt -o final_results.txt
echo "All Done!"
```

**2) Call R script from within Python**

There are a couple ways to do this, the first is with `os.system`:

```
import os
print('Do things in python here')
# Now call the R script
os.system('Rscript myrscript.r')
```

Or with the `subprocess` module:

```
import subprocess
print('Do things in python here')
# Now open a subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['Rscript', 'myrscript.r'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p.wait()
data = p.stdout.read()
print(data)
```

**3) Embed R code directly in Python code with `rpy`**

I don't have much experience with this package, so I'll just point you to the documentation for this one: https://rpy2.bitbucket.io/